# How to set the max number of text rows (wraps) in a td?

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table border="3">
        <tr> <td class="table_class">111111 222222 333333 </td> <td class="table_class">234 </td> </tr>
        <tr> <td class="table_class">2321</td> <td class="table_class">ssS</td> </tr>
    </table>

.table_class {
    width: 20px;
}
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/Nzd9K/

How can I "capture" numbers of rows in TD? For example,I would like max two rows in TD. I can use substr, but this isn't good idea. Extra text let be cut off.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the extra text? Should it be cut off? Clearly, only so much text can fix inside 2 lines with `20px` width.

Comment: What do you want to happen to the "excess" content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add a wrapper `div` with `overflow: hidden` inside each `td`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/Nzd9K/17/

```
<td class="table_class"><div>111111 222222 333333</div></td>

.table_class div {
    height: 2.5em; /* adjust to taste */
    overflow: hidden
}
```